# error in creating a media folder using Media.makeNew

Tags: umbraco

I've upgraded my umbraco to 4.7.1.1
when I create a new content item, I write it in my db and I have a task that calls a web-service that creates
a media folder accordingly

this works well from the WS in my computer (with the production DB),
but when i run the WS from the production server I get this error on media.createNew(name, new MediaType(1031), new User(0), parentId):

node: Could not find a IDataType control matching DataEditorId cccd4ae9-f399-4ed2-8038-2e88d19e810c in the controls collection. To correct this, check the data type definition in the developer section or ensure that the package/control is installed correctly.======   at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.controls.Factory.GetNewObject(Guid DataEditorId)     at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property.MakeNew(PropertyType pt, Content c, Guid versionId)     at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Content.createNewVersion()     at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Content.CreateContent(ContentType ct)     at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media.MakeNew(String Name, MediaType dct, User u, Int32 ParentId)     at Netcraft.Utilities.Common.MediaHandler.CreateNode(String name, Int32 parentId, Int32 contentId) in C:..\Common\MediaHandler.cs:line 29     at Netcraft.Utilities.Common.MediaHandler.CreateMediaFolder(Document document) in C:..\Common\MediaHandler.cs:line 79     at Netcraft.WebService.EventManagerService.Execute() in C:..\EventManagerService.asmx.cs:line 75==============

the dlls and configs are identical, I understand he's looking for the folder control.. what is the problem?

when the code is finished, a new folder is created but when i click it i get :

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Property contents (27) on Content Type Folder could not be retrieved for Document 21741 on Tab Page Contents. To fix this problem, delete the property and recreate it.

Update: 
I looked up the control id (cccd4ae9-f399-4ed2-8038-2e88d19e810c),
it's MediaFolder which sounds like a standard control(?)

where should i check if it's installed?

I'm capable of creating a media folder manually
and the test from my local environment (a webservice on my computer pointing to the prod DB) , created a media folder on the production env..
what does this mean?

I'm an umbraco newbie :)

thanks!

Igal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out..
the webservice i was using , had an application pool that didn't have permissions on the media folder.
that fixed it!